# Eclipse Indigo with Closure

Tags: eclipse, google-closure-compiler, eclipse-indigo, google-closure

I installed correctly the plugin for CLOSURE, i followed the steps from here http://www.normalesup.org/~simonet/soft/ow/eclipse-closure-javascript.en.html and then when i try to do the first simple example helloword -> https://developers.google.com/closure/library/docs/gettingstarted eclipse platform don't have the packages and the library ( repeat i enabled and instaled the library correctly) .

I have try to add the library to the js project difrectly but that its a big problem because while eclipse building the workspace with the changes (at 38% progress process) then dont works any more. Does anyone happen the same? Anyone knows great site for search info or dowload a good version with the pluggin?

Answer (score 0):

Have you set/checked the "Closure Base Directory" property in Eclipse preferences, Javascript -> Closure?

(note, "Closure Base Directory" should be set to the full path to base.js, excluding the filename but including "/goog/", not the "/closure/" or "/closure-library/" directory)